# how to connect external database in drupal 7?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7, database-connection

Drupal 7 installed and working fine with the database named "DrupalDB". The another database "CustomDB" contains one table.
how to connect "CustomDB" in drupal 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can see the `settings.php` file(the place db information is stored) in where the Drupal 7 installation.in there you can see a array like this.

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'db-name',
      'username' => 'db-username',
      'password' => 'db-password',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

To allow modules to quickly make connections to other databases, you’ll need to add additional information to the `$databases` array:

```
$databases['CustomDB']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'CustomDB',
  'username' => 'CustomDB-username',
  'password' => 'CustomDB-password',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

You can see, this code defines another database identified by the array key `CustomDB`. So when you need to query this other database in your modules, you have to switch the connection to it with this function:

```
db_set_active('CustomDB');
```

the,you have to close it and revert back to the default database connection in order for `Drupal` to be able to access its data

```
db_set_active();
```

As you don’t pass a parameter to function `db_set_active()`, it will switch back to the default database